# Is there a 3rd party .NET library/assembly that will parse & import files using a metadata-driven approach?

Tags: .net, metadata, data-importer, file-processing

I need to parse a bunch of delimited flat files and import them into a database. I could build my own simple metadata-driven parser and importer but figure there must be something like this out there already?

Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)? It will do this, as well as the sorts of cleanup or other manipulation frequently required after parsing flat files.

Comment: Thanks for you post John. SSIS is an option I guess. Not especially keen on using this for enterprise-level software though where you need comprehensive logging & diagnostics...

Comment: SSIS has a very good story around logging and diagnostics! You can even write your own log provider and integrate it, with no change to the packages. What concerns do you have? It's ok in 2005, and kicks ass in 2008.